# Need tag synonym created for microsoft-word-mac2011

Tags: support, tag-synonym-request

I created a new [microsoft-word-mac2011](https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-word-mac2011/info) but now see it is the same as [microsoft-word-2011](https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-word-2011/info) and should be a synonym of that tag.  I think we should have both because I mistakenly thought the existing one was for Windows, so having mac in the name clarifies things.  However, I don't have sufficient reputation to do this, so would someone please help create a synonym that has the ability?

Comment: Why not simply delete the one you created?  The current one matches the other tags for Office/Word.  Your suggestion would merit the creation of `microsoft-word-pc2013` which makes no sense.

Comment: I've suggested edits to all the questions tagged [tag:microsoft-word-mac2011] to make the tags what they should be. The tag will be removed automatically if it is not on any single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the tag [microsoft-word-mac2011](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word-mac2011) out of all the questions that use it. The tag will automatically be burninated by the system soon.

In the meantime, I request that such tags be blacklisted so that they are not created by other users later on.

**UPDATE:** The tag has now been burninated.